# Does a ROB exist in CPUs with in-order pipe-line?

Tags: x86, arm, cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture

We know that a ROB exists in CPUs with out-of-order pipelines to reorder u-instructions that are executed in out-of-order manner. Could anyone tell me whether or not a ROB exists in CPUs with in-order pipeline? If yes what is the duty of this structure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about CPU design, not computer programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in-order execution pipelines can let instructions *finish* execution out of order after starting in-order (especially loads are commonly allowed to do this, letting static instruction scheduling help hide load latency).  All of this is possible without a ROB.  Just scoreboarding register writes is enough to enable that, I think, even for letting ALU instructions as well as loads finish out of order.

AFAIK, having a ROB is only necessary / worthwhile / has any point for a CPU that can *start* execution of instructions out of order.  Hence the name ROB = ReOrder Buffer.

(And a microarchitecture would normally track not-yet-executed instructions in the RS / scheduler as well.  ROB tracks from issue to retire; RS tracks from issue to execute.  That's using the terminology where "issue" means allocating instructions from the front-end into the out-of-order back-end.  Some people call this "dispatch".)

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. So as your response I can conclude that Cortex-A8 CPU that incorporates in-order pipeline does not contain ROB at all. I know that it maybe is an irrelevant question, but if Cortex-A8 is an inorder CPU and does not have ROB, so how is it vulnerable to Spectre type attacks?

Comment: @alirezasadeghpour: I don't think any in-order CPUs are vulnerable to any form of Spectre.  They can fetch / decode speculatively, but don't get as far as executing speculatively.  Hit under miss / miss under miss caches are not sufficient to produce secret-data-dependent changes in architectural state from mispredicted branches.  Do you have some evidence that A8 is vulnerable?

Comment: as https://developer.arm.com/support/arm-security-updates/speculative-processor-vulnerability indicated, A8 is vulnerable against SpectreV1(bound check bypass) and SpectreV2(Branch target injection). however, I could not implement POC of those attacks in TI AM335x that is a Cortex-a8 CPU.

Comment: Hmm, maybe A8 starts memory access early enough for it to leave some trace in the shadow of a mispredicted conditional or indirect branch, or maybe Wikipedia is wrong about how in-order it is, or maybe I'm wrong about in-order cores not being vulnerable.  You should ask a separate question about how A8 specifically can be vulnerable to Spectre V1 and V2 (or if ARM is wrong and it isn't).  I don't know that level of detail about ARM microarchitectures; x86 is my main area.